# (Mac) Cocoa app change core dump location

Tags: macos, cocoa, coredump

If my application crashes i wish for the coredump file to be stored in a particular directory. It is possible to change the location from the command line but i wish my application to change this path  programatically and if possible only for a single (its self) application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. But if you're not sandboxed, you can look at the files in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticLogs and move them somewhere else the next time you're launched.